# window.showModalDialog dialogHeight / dialogWidth don't appear to be working in IE 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, showmodaldialog

Having been marooned on IE 6 for 10 years the company I work for has suddenly announced that we're migrating to IE 8 for our intranet apps.  Having taken a quick look all seems to work fine in IE 8 for ours but there seems to be a quirk with window.showModalDialog that I was wondering if anyone could help with?

Basically the code below is executed in IE6 and opens up a window of the width / height I would expect:

```
//Set options
var sOptions = 'dialogWidth:247px; dialogHeight:181px; dialogLeft:100px; dialogTop:100px; status:no; scroll:no; help:no; resizable:yes';

//Open dialog
var oValue = window.showModalDialog(sURL, null, sOptions);
```

However, in IE 8 (or I guess IE 7 given that on intranet apps it will be forced to "Compatibility Mode") the dialog is opened with a larger width / height.

Does anyone know what might be causing this?  I've a vague idea there might be a minimum width / height being enforced but I can't find any documentation to back this up...

Comment: I've been trying to reproduce your problem, but I haven't been able to. Could you provide a little more information regarding your problem? Or maybe a screenshot :D?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't reproduce it myself at the moment as I'm not allowed to install IE 8 on my machine.  But I can see it when I look over peoples shoulders.  Looking at the size of the modal dialog in IE 8 it opens up at about 259x277 pixels if that helps.  Ironically Firefox works fine :-) (but Firefox is also not "authorised")

Comment: Firefox always works fine ;D! It's always a pain when the company decides to support older technology. While I haven't been able to reproduce your problem in IE9(using IE7, 8 and 9 standards), you could try using CSS conditionals to display a specific size when the browser is IE8. [CSS Conditionals](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)

Comment: Thanks Mario - I'll look into this.... The company are not making this particular task easy to achieve!